# Binding event to dynamically added elements to DOM using jQuery

Tags: html, dom, jquery

I'm dynamically adding few elements to DOM. And I want to manipulate these element behavior using `.on()` function of jQuery. But somehow DOM is not firing `.on()` event for dynamically added elements.

Here is JS Fiddle that shows the example - http://jsfiddle.net/jYQ2D/1/

When I click on "Dynamically Added in HTML" button, it should show alert message but it is not showing.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delegation via `.on` doesn't work that way.  You have to call `.on` on the element and then use the second argument as the delegation selector:

```
$(document).on("click", "#dyna", function() {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jYQ2D/2/

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  Also be aware that there can be only one `#dyna` element.